# Add a Temporary Property on a Node Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Is it possible to SET a property on node and REMOVE it within a single cypher query without causing an actual disk write in Neo4j.

For example, I tried duplicating the n node in this query using n as errand but a SET on errand results to a SET on n and equally the REMOVE such the property is lost in the return value.

This is sort of my attempt at creating a transient property on a node.

```
String q = "MATCH (owner)-[:POSTED]->n WITH owner, n, n as errand, 
      CASE WHEN owner-[:RECOMMENDED]->n THEN 'BROADCASTED' 
      WHEN owner-[:POSTED]->n THEN 'POSTED' 
      WHEN owner-[:GOT_NOMINATED]->n THEN 'NOMINATED' 
      ELSE 'CONNECTED' 
      END AS relationship 
SET errand.meta = relationship 
REMOVE n.meta 
RETURN errand LIMIT 1";
```

However, when ever I check my domain object to see if the property was set by Neo4j, it returns null.

```
public class Errand {
     private String meta;

     Boolean isMetaSet () {
          return meta != null;
     }
}
```

Using SDN Neo4j I get my errand object like.

```
Errand single = template.query(q, null).to(Errand.class).singleOrNull();

System.out.println (single.isMetaSet());
```

returns false.

Is the answer in
[Neo4J create temp variable within Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375229) applicable for Nodes?

I am currently using Neo4j in Embedded Mode with Neo4j, and my queries are run using the Neo4jTemplate class.

See the response to a similar question I asked on this issue at [Set a transient property on a node neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028632/set-a-transient-property-on-a-node-neo4j)

Comment: I would like to return a single node deserializable into my model object

Comment: Great answer to when trying to return a property.

Comment: This causes a null pointer exception because it is removed before it is returned. Is there something wrong with my cypher query?

Comment: Rephrased my question

Comment: Please update the question to show what code is populating the Errand object on the basis of that query.  And have you tried not binding `n` twice, once to itself, once to `errand` in the WITH block?

Comment: That didn't work. I thought that would even out if I SET and REMOVE in a single query. Question updated.

Comment: So if you're saying `n` and `errand` are the same thing, why is this result suprising?  You remove `errand.meta` and then return `n`, meaning `errand.meta` **should be null**.  So if meta is null, then return meta != null returns false, and this behavior is expected.  What is the problem  here?

Comment: Exactly, so this means you answer is not applicable for nodes. Your answer seems to work for an arbitrary property.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not need a temporary node property or a special variable at all. (Also, as @FrobberOfBits said, your approach was flawed.)

The following query eliminates `errand` (which was just an alias for the `n` node), and also sets the `n.meta` property:

```
MATCH (owner)-[:POSTED]->n
SET n.meta =
      CASE WHEN owner-[:RECOMMENDED]->n THEN 'BROADCASTED' 
      WHEN owner-[:POSTED]->n THEN 'POSTED' 
      WHEN owner-[:GOT_NOMINATED]->n THEN 'NOMINATED' 
      ELSE 'CONNECTED' 
      END
RETURN n.meta LIMIT 1
```

(Since you are limiting to 1, there is no need to use `DISTINCT`.)

Comment: You answer seems to deviate from the question. Could you please look into how we can set a temporary property on a NODE in Neo4j?

Comment: This is quite different from creating an arbitrary variable within Neo4j which is what @FrobberOfBits answered  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375229

Comment: The question's subject line is about temporary node properties, not variables -- they are completely different things. Also the question's first link points to a question whose accepted answer had to do with node properties. Finally, the query provided in the question did not actually need to do anything fancy to get back a single `relationship` value, so I provided a more direct query. Are you saying that your whole question actually was asking how to set the `meta` property?

Comment: I've modified my answer to do that as well.

Comment: A node n is has three properties persisted in database. You want to add a fourth temporary property meta to the node which is visible only in the returned node but not in the database how do we do it?